# Find where a collection is created in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle, collections, oracle-apex

I am working on an already built **Apex 5.1** application. I need to modify the way a **collection** is created. Problem is: I cannot find **where** it's created in the application.

Is there a way to find where this collection is instanced ? I only have the **name** of it.

I know in Apex 4.2 I could find it within any page in the last rows of the navigation tree.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have to search for *something*, I do exactly that: *search* for it.

I can't remember how 5.x "search" looks like exactly, but it should be a *magnifier* icon, somewhere at the top of the screen. It allows you to search the current page, or the whole application. So - you'd enter collection's name and search the application. Hopefully, you'll find it.

Comment: Omg, I thought it was for searching for a specific application. Thank you so much I found it ! I kinda feel ashamed :D